# PHPExcel file is not downloading

Tags: php

I'm attempting to download a spreadsheet using PHPExcel but so far nothing but a blank page.

```
$items = array("test 1", "test 2", "test 3");

/** PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
//echo date('H:i:s') . " Create new PHPExcel object\n";
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("User 1");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("User 1");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle(" Quotes");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Quotes");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Quotes");

// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$loop = 0;
foreach($items as $value) {

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('No', $loop);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Item Name', $value);

    $loop++;
}

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="quotes.xls"');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

I've enabled errors and still blank page.
How do i solve?  No file is downloading?

Comment: You start by looking at your logs, perhaps do a little debugging

Comment: I've looked at my logs, found nothing relating to this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you should should be getting errors, or something written to your logs, because your code will throw a fatal

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'Invalid cell coordinate NO' in ...
```

Because `NO` is not a valid cell address in an Excel worksheet, nor is `Item Name`

The problem is these lines:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('No', $loop);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Item Name', $value);
```

A valid cell address is a column (like `A`) combined with a row (like `1`) to give a cell address of `A1`

Perhaps you meant something like:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.($loop+1), 'No');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.($loop+1), 'Item Name');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.($loop+1), $loop);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.($loop+1), $value);
```

Comment: Thanks, i've got it downloading now by doing your changes but i also had to move the file to the same folder `PHPExcel` is in.  Also the file is in gibberish but thanks for the help.

Comment: That "Gibberish" is the binary xls file, but if it's not opening in Excel then you probably have something from your code injecting additional output into the php://output stream